# How to do an OR in LINQ from statement

Tags: linq

I am trying to write a LINQ query where I want to access data from two different tables depending on what the front end sends back
if `FlowerClients` is being sent from the front end, I want to use `FlowerClient` table OR if data being sent is for `AnotherClient` use AnotherClient.

Is this possible to do in LINQ or is it better to create different methods?

```
var flowerById = (from flower in flowerContext.Flowers
        where flower.FlowerId == flowerId
        join petals in flowerContext.Petals on flower.PetalId equals petals.PetalId
        from flowerClients in flowerContext.FlowerClients.Where(x => x.FlowerId == flower.FlowerId).DefaultIfEmpty()
        ||
        from anotherFlowerClients in flowerContext.AnotherClients.Where(x => x.FlowerId == flower.FlowerId).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: You should write two queries separated by an `if`/`else`.  That will probably be the most readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to create different methods, particularly if the `FlowerClients` and `AnotherClients` classes are very different.

Otherwise, you could dynamically generate your query expression. You will probably want to make sure that `FlowerClients` and `AnotherClients` implement a common interface however that way you don't have to do any sort of mapping between the two.

```
IQueryable<FlowerPetal> query1 = flowerContext.Flowers
    .Where(f => f.FlowerId == flowerId)
    .Join(flowerContext.Petals,
        f => f.PetalId,
        p => p.PetalId,
        (f, p) => new FlowerPetal { Flower = f, Petal = p }
    );

IQueryable<FlowerPetalClient> WithClients(IQueryable<FlowerPetal> _query, IQueryable<IClient> _clients) =>
    _query.SelectMany(
        x => _clients.Where(c => c.FlowerId == x.Flower.FlowerId).DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, c) => new FlowerPetalClient { Flower = x.Flower, Petal = x.Petal, Client = c }
    );

IQueryable<IClient> clients = useFlowerClients // decide on which client to use
    ? flowerContext.FlowerClients
    : flowerContext.AnotherClients;
var query = WithClients(query1, clients); // expand on query
```

with some helper classes:

```
class FlowerPetal
{
    public Flower Flower { get; set; }
    public Petal Petal { get; set; }
}
class FlowerPetalClient
{
    public Flower Flower { get; set; }
    public Petal Petal { get; set; }
    public IClient Client { get; set; }
}
```